# Taping for calf cramps

Tags: cramps, ultimate-frisbee

Once a month, I play three games of ultimate frisbee in a single day for an ongoing competition. I usually start getting calf cramps halfway through the third game.

Now, I know the main ways to prevent this (proper hydration, conditioning, magnesium), but they do not guarantee that the problem does not occur. Since I have plenty of recovery time afterwards, I'm looking for tricks to finish the game if the cramp does hit.

I notice that the cramps hit when the muscle is fully flexed. would it help to tape tightly around the whole lower leg at one or two places, to stop the calf from fully flexing? I guess I wouldn't run at my maximum speed, but that's better than not running at all.

Answer (score 2):

Taping for a cramp seems to be an excessive measure considering the causes are [many](http://www.webmd.com/pain-management/muscle-spasms-cramps-charley-horse), and, the taping may actually exacerbate the situation if it affects circulation.  Since there's no definitive study to indicate the exact causes for cramps (there seem to be many possibilities), I think your best course of action is to prepare yourself ahead of time.

I have a similar situation as a rower.  During practice, it's not unusual to row for 20 minutes without a break.  This may be repeated several times over the course of practice.  There's no guarantee that a cramp will not rear it's ugly head even making sure that I consume the right amount of water, nutrients, etc.  I have only anecdotal evidence, but, in my case, I've found that following a **stretching program** for my calves before rowing, and, keeping my calves **warm** cuts down on the frequency of calf cramps.  It may be related to increased blood flow.  I use a neoprene calf sleeve that's made specifically for rowing that provides protection and warmth.  Here's a sample...

[image]

While the sleeve isn't a preventative, it seems to cut down on the frequency of cramps.  If you've exhausted all other solutions, it may be worth trying a calf sleeve.